# Using WSO2 API Manager and Rsync, configure both nodes to publish to Manager node

Tags: wso2, rsync

I have configured WSO2 API Manager 2.5.0 in a Active/Active Deployment following [Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment).

I am unable to maintain a shared file system, so I have configured rsync to synchronize following [Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Configuring+rsync+for+Deployment+Synchronization).

So, in my deployment, I have a load balancer, and two nodes:

- node 1 (for rsync is the manager node), with the IP 10.0.0.101
- node 2 (for rsync is a worker node), with the IP 10.0.0.102

In **order to both nodes publish to node1, I have done the specific changes** in Step 4 and Step 5 of the first provided link of Documentation:

- Edit */repository/conf/api-manager.xml* of node 1 is not necesary because it publish to itself.
- I have edited */repository/conf/api-manager.xml* of node 2 in order to it publish to Gateway of node 1 (10.0.0.101 ). Thus:

code

```
<APIGateway>
    <Environments>
        <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
            ...
            <ServerURL>https://10.0.0.101:9443/services/</ServerURL>
            ...
        </Environment>
    </Environments>
</APIGateway>
```

But **how can I test that it is working?**.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test this by creating an API by logging into the publisher of node 2 (10.0.0.102), And you could see the necessary artefacts will get created in the /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default directory.

Comment: This is not an adquate answer, please rather consider to post it as a comment.